# How to use ModelState to clear my form after I post my form data,my view model is a viewmodel which has two models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

my view model is a viewmodel which has two models,

```
  publish class ViewModel
  { 
  public Student StudentModel{get;set;}
  public Teacher TeacherModel {get;set;}
  }
```

I has two forms called StudentForm and TeacherForm,Which binding StudentModel and TeacherModel respectively.Now I fill in some data in StudentForm and submit it. I use `ModelState.Clear();` to clear my StudentForm data ,but It seems not only clear the data of the StudentForm but also the TeacherForm,How can I only clear the data of the StudentForm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to shorten, you may just do

```
foreach (var key in ModelState.Keys.Where(m => m.StartsWith("StudentModel")).ToList())
                ModelState.Remove(key);
```

Comment: +1. Short and nice code. can you please help why `ModelState.Keys.Where(i => i.StartsWith("MyProperty1")).ToList().Clear();` this is not working ? This is not removing the key !!!

Comment: @PKKG because `ToList()` creates a new List of keys (which is in fact just a list of strings), which has now nothing to do with ModelState instance. With `Clear()`, you just Clear that new list... You now have an empty list of strings, and have done nothing to your ModelState.

Answer (score 2):

In such case you will have to remove each property of `StudentModel` from your `ModelState` i.e.

**Syntax:**

```
ModelState.Remove("PropertyName");
```

**Example:**

```
ModelState.Remove("Id"); 
ModelState.Remove("Name"); 
ModelState.Remove("Marks");
```

**Edit: For specific model property in among two**

```
ModelState.Remove("StudentModel.Name");
```

Comment: But My StudentModel has a propertyname called Name,and my TeacherModel also has a propertyname called Name.In this way,it seems that I have to make sure that these model in the same view must has different propertyname.

Answer (score 1):

`ModelState.Remove("StudentForm")`,Here is the MSDN link for this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470162%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

While returning the model from action you can reinitialize the student object

For eg:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActionName(ViewModel model)
    {
       model.StudentModel = new StudentModel();
       return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: I would have tried the same, with a ModelState.Clear(); But I guess that's what @user2374716 has already tried

Comment: Hi,I just use this in a pop up window,means that I don't want to refresh the viewpage.Maybe this is not the way for me, but also to thank you for the answer

Comment: but `ModelState.Clear();` will clear the whole view model. and only reinitializing the StudentModel as I have done will only clear the StudentModel and not other.

Comment: Yes,but `return View(model);` may refresh the page,and `ModelState.Remove("StudentModel.Name");` do not refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Note: ModelState Key contains your ViewModel Name, like:

**ModelState.Remove("YourViewModelName.YourPropertyName");**